# How can I ask the user for the numbers after asking for the number of numbers to use in a calculation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I'm new to python, and I'm working on a simple calculator to learn more about it, and I'm not sure how to solve this. I'm trying to make my calculator scalable, so the user can choose how many numbers they calculate with, so that it isn't hard-coded to only two numbers.

The calculator so far:

```
import operator

ops = {
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "^": operator.pow
}

calc_start = ["Welcome to the Calculator! ", " ", "Choose an operation. "]
print("\n".join(calc_start))

op_choice = ["*", "/", "+", "-", "^"]
print("\n".join(op_choice))

calc_stop= False
while not calc_stop == True:
    # Ask the user for an operation
    choice = input("Enter your choice here: ")
    if choice in op_choice:
        try:
            # Ask the user for numbers
            num1 = float(input("Enter your first number here: "))
            num2 = float(input("Enter your next number here: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input: please enter a number. ")
            continue
        # Calculate and print equation
        result = ops[choice](num1, num2)
        print(num1, choice, num2, "=", result)
        # Ask user if they want to calculate again
        valid_answer1 = "n"
        valid_answer2 = "y"
        next_calculation = input("Would you like to do another calculation? (y/n) ")
        for i in next_calculation:
            if i in valid_answer1:
                print("Goodbye!")
                calc_stop = True
            if i in valid_answer2:
                print("Preparing next calculation...")
                print(" ")
                continue
    else:
        print("Invalid Input.")
```

I've tried a function, but i'm not sure how to use it while not writing a million `if` statements.

```
def multi_num(stop):
    num_total = int(input("How many numbers would you like to calculate with? "))
    if num_total <= 1:
        print("Error: please enter more than 1. ")
        stop = True
    if num_total = 2:
        num1 = float(input("Enter your first number here: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter your second number here: "))
    if num_total = 3:
        num1 = float(input("Enter your first number here: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter your second number here: "))
        num3 = float(input("Enter your third number here: "))
```

Comment: Sure! Instead of having `num1` and `num2`, create a list of inputs and append each new user input onto it. The only pain would be having a list of ordinals (but that's probably unnecessary anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop the get the numbers and store them in a array:

```py
def input_numbers(n):
    numbers = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        try:
            num = float(input(f"Enter your {i} number: "))
            numbers.append(num)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number.")
    return numbers

n = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
result = input_numbers(n)
print("Entered numbers:", result)
```